# Set up description meta automatically

Tags: wp-head, description

How I can setup/override meta description tag values for arbitrary pages of my site? I have a lot of pages, generated dynamically by script. I need to add dynamically generated meta description for all of these pages. How can I do it using standard Wordpress abilities?

I don't want to use plugins for this task.

A solution using filters is highly preferrable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use first few lines of post content and add these to meta description tags to website head section automatically.

Here is how you do that.

```
// add meta description tag
function wcs_add_meta_description_tag() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $meta = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
        $meta = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
        $meta = str_replace( array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $meta );
        $meta = mb_substr( $meta, 0, 125, 'utf8' );
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $meta . '" />' . "\n";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wcs_add_meta_description_tag' , 2 );
```

Ofcourse You can change this code to use post excerpt for meta description tag.

Comment: `substr()` will create invalid UTF-8. [Use `mb_substr()` instead.](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/)